# C# Function not working correctly

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am new to using visual studio for C# at least.
I can blow through C# in Unity all day long, however,
I am having a really hard time trying to understand why this function isn't running correctly.

The (Console Lines) > DO RUN.
But nothing else works, period.

Here's the first code - it's a button - (which does work).

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveLastUsage(); // Save Variables.
        CreateAddTab();
    }


    public void CreateAddTab()
    {
        CanvasSmith main = new CanvasSmith();
        main.AddTab();
    }
```

However, as I mentioned - CONSOLE LINES DO RUN, But not the actual Tab Controls.

```
     public void AddTab()
    {

        this.tabArea = new TabControl();

        this.tabArea.Visible = true;
        Console.WriteLine("I AM RUNNING");
        string title = "TabPage " + (this.tabArea.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        this.tabArea.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);


        // ALSO TRIED IT LIKE
        // tabArea.Visible = true;
        //Console.WriteLine("I AM RUNNING");
        //string title = "TabPage " + (tabArea.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        //TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        //tabArea.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    }
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
But literally - Nothing at all runs except console lines.
No errors, nothing - just don't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To make it easier for other people to help you, please include an exact description of the problem. What is the behavior of the code now? And how do you expect/want it to behave?

Comment: What is `CanvasSmith main`? Do you add it to the UI anywhere?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your messages! Right now I have two forms, One - Main Form - where the tabs are. And another that creates the tabs (it is a painting program). So making a new texture window thing... Well The button on new texture window works, but only console lines appear to be being called.... What I am trying to do is (make the tabs invisible - which I do). But upon creating a new texture make them visible and create a tab.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the last line of code. Does your `myTabPage` get instantiated correctly? Does `tabArea.TabPages` contain the freshly added myTabPage? If no, the problem is deeper inside the respective objects and you have to repeat this process at class level.

Comment: I suspect you use "console app" as template instead WinForm/WPF... You need to provide complete [MCVE] so one can reproduce problem to get real answer (one provided by Blaatz0r seem plausible *if* you actually start with WinForm app)

Comment: I have no idea if it is or isn't. It's just plainly not doing anything except running Console Lines. It's not even trying to work. like the whole, tabArea.Visible = true; don't even work. But yet on the form_Load section it works like it should.

Comment: Like everything else works fine - i can run all kinds of components, but it's not working unless it's called inside the Load_Form area.

Comment: The Debug console is as well saying it's WinForms loading.

Comment: But like I mentioned - if I throw the code to add the tabs, etc. Into the Load function for the form - it works. But just not inside the public void AddTab(). Which is being called - just not the code for the Tab Control.

Comment: I'm about to just re-install VS 2013, just tested a new app and I made 2 forms, each one with a button, Form1 Button opens form2, Form2 Button Hides Form1, but it doesn't do anything, yet again.

Answer (score 1):

I FINALLY GOT IT! I had to Cast it!

all I had to do was change the way I was calling my reference to the main form.

changed CanvasSmith main = new CanvasSmith();

to

main = CanvasSmi.ActiveForm as CanvasSmi;

So I casted it and now it works like a charm :D
I appreciate everyones ideas though, but finally got it 12 hours later haha.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your control to a form.
I assume this <- points to a Form object.
Otherwise you should give some more information regarding the setup of your project.

Eg.

```
public void AddTab()
{

    this.tabArea = new TabControl();

    this.tabArea.Visible = true;
    Console.WriteLine("I AM RUNNING");
    string title = "TabPage " + (this.tabArea.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    this.tabArea.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

    this.Controls.Add(tabArea);
}
```

Comment: Ps. you don't always need to use 'this'

Comment: Just tried it still doesn't work :(. And yeah it's a form component. What I'm doing is, the button is on another form, so I reference the main form (where the tab control is at) and run the block of code inside the main form, and it just runs the Console lines. And I know about this this thing, I was just trying it because I saw it on the MSDN website, so just tried it like that.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share some more code? That way it would be easier for me and others to determine what might be the issue :)

Comment: I just tried 4 times to post both scripts I have - but it keeps complaining of formatting errors. I'm sorry man.

Comment: Could it possibly be a bug in VS? Because I could have sworn I did it in VS 2013 yesterday, but unisntalled and install 2015 today and started project over - just can't remember if I did it or not, but could have sworn I did.